# RMI classsloader

Tags: java, classloader

I'm doing a RMI call within the one `.ear`, yet when I check the class loader of an object returned by the RMI call, it gives another `.ear`'s class loader. Can anyone tell me which class loader it should have used when deserializing the object?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you are using the codebase feature, and also whether you are using Java RMI or some vendor's 'equivalent', some of which break the rules.